# Customize anchor-sections.css with blogdown

Tags: blogdown

I saw in the [`html_document` help page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/html_document.html#anchor-sections-customization) an easy-way to customize the anchor style by adapting the `anchor-section` class. This works well for individual Rmd documents.

I would like to know how to achieve the same thing within `blogdown`. I thought that I could simply customize the `static/rmarkdown-libs/anchor-sections/anchor-sections.css` file.

This actually work temporarily, but is not working properly since this file is automatically regenerated every time any Rmd file is rendered.

I'm sorry I did not include a reprex, this is more of a technical question.

Comment: You shouldn't modify any files under `static/rmarkdown-libs/` since it is automatically created and will be overwritten, as you have discovered. You need to create another CSS file under `static/`, and include it in one of your (or your theme's) template files in the `layouts/` folder. The precise way to to include it depends on the theme you use. Without a reprex, it's hard to tell you a general solution. You may study this minimal theme to understand how things work: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html and hopefully figure out how to make your custom CSS work with your theme.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie - I was finally able to do what I want by creating a `/static/css/custom.css` file that I added in my Rmd YAML header with `css: "/css/custom.css"`. This way, I keep your library (the js code is perfect for my need) and I overwrite your style.

Comment: That surely works, but you'd have to do this for every post. If you could include it in a template file, it will work for all pages. As I said, it's too hard to tell what you need to do precisely because it depends on the theme, and we are not given the source of your site (if it's on Github, a link to your repo would be enough).

Comment: The source is here: https://github.com/jplecavalier/personal-website/tree/dev. Note that I still have not push a single blog post, I'm still working on my first, it should be up soon.

Comment: This is where your theme loads CSS files: https://github.com/jplecavalier/personal-website/blob/dev/themes/hugo-academic/layouts/partials/site_head.html I'm not familiar with the codebase of the academic theme, but I'm sure you can at least add a line like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">` to the template.